# How to call function inside d3.json()

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to load in my data from a .json file to create a treemap. Everything works fine except for when I call a helper function inside the d3.json() I get the error

```
Cannot read property 'zoomin' of undefined
```

My code looks like this

```
d3.json("../static/warehouses.json").then(function(data){
//do stuff here for treemap
      this.zoomin() //function to zoom in on a clicked treemap node
    })
```

How can I include a helper function in the d3.json function if thats even possible? If not how can I get around that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `this` context.
You can store `this` in some variable and call zoomin using it.

```
let self = this;
d3.json("../static/warehouses.json").then(function(data){
//do stuff here for treemap
      self.zoomin() //function to zoom in on a clicked treemap node
})
```

Hope it helps.